# Get all from left to repeat on right

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, Chart_mst and UnitCd1_mst.  There is nothing to join on the 2 tables.  I need a query for all the accounts in chart_mst that have unit1 avaiable to them by a column in the chart of accounts called access_unit1.  I need the acct (from chart_mst) to repeat for every unit1 (from unitcs1_mst).  So my query would look something like

```
select acct, unit1 from chart_mst, unitcd1_mst where acctest_unit1 <> 'n'.
```

I need:

```
10000 10
10000 20
10000 30
10001 10
10001 20
10001 30
etc.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Make it easy to assist, also provide sample table data (matching the expected result.)

Comment: Pretty sure i did

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing a `cross join`:

```
select *
from Chart_mst cross join
     UnitCd1_mst;
```